# Pythonic OOP and sklearn/numpy optimization

Tags: python-3.x, oop, scikit-learn

I get into this issue very often, I develop my code using OOP and when I want to use numpy, sklearn modules or any other "matrix" speeded up procedures I can't figure out the best way of doing it without looping all objects again.

For instance, I have an object called Particle which have a coordinate x:

```
class Particle(object):
     def __init__(self, x):
         self.x = x
```

and then I create a bunch of them like:

```
from numpy.random import random
np = 100
p = []
points = random((np, 3))
for i in range(np):
    p.append(Particle(points[i, :]))
```

Finally, I would like to get the distance between particles. To do so, I could use a brute force search and evaluate the norm of the distances or use an optimized module to do it faster, like:

```
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import pairwise_distances
pairwise_distances(X=points)
```

Yet, this way I have no advantage of using OOP.

I have tried something weird like:

```
pairwise_distances(X=p[:].x)
```

but of course, it doesn't work.

Another example I crossed with is related to the [predator-prey model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lotka%E2%80%93Volterra_equations). Ideally, from a numerical perspective, I would assemble each animal in a matrix form so it would be faster to solve, yet from an OOP I created an animal object with its constants within and to solve it I got into messed and slow code.

Is there a way to work around these issues in an elegant pythonic way?
Should I choose to program in one way over the other?

Thank you.

Comment: what is your `random` function? What is the shape of `points`, which you feed to `pairwise_distances`

Comment: @AI_Learning I used the `from numpy.random import random`.

Comment: @AI_Learning `points` is a matrix with dimensions np x 3. Where each line represents the 3 coordinates of a point.